# How do jemalloc and tcmalloc track threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, tcmalloc, jemalloc

Now I am actively studying the code of memory managers `jemalloc` and `tcmalloc`. But I can't understand how these two managers track threads.

If I understand correctly, a new thread can be detected during memory allocation, after which a new thread cache is created. But how does `tcmalloc` / `jemalloc` detect when a thread is destroyed and the thread cache attached to it can be freed for a future use?

Google results could not give even a minimum of any useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only answer for jemalloc, but the way it works is that when the thread cache is created it is associated with the thread specific data for that thread.

When you create thread specific data, you can give it a 'destructor', which is invoked when the thread is being destroyed. If you're using pthreads it's the [pthread_key_create](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/pthread_key_create.html) routine, which is the C way of creating thread specific data.

In the case of jemalloc, there is a bit of code in `tcache.h`, which hooks `tcache_thread_cleanup` with the `tcache` data (my source jemalloc-3.0.0):

```
143 malloc_tsd_funcs(JEMALLOC_INLINE, tcache, tcache_t *, NULL,
144     tcache_thread_cleanup)
```

So when the thread is exited, the destructor gets called. It gets given the pointer to the cache for that thread and runs the `tcache_thread_cleanup` routine at that time.